# Folder in Reposity can't be open in github

Tags: git, github

[image]

I'm a new, after push project in repository I can't open the folder. how to fixed it ?

Answer (score 1):

That symbol means that the `google-auth` directory is actually a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules): a pointer to another git repository. You can't click on the link in github because it point at a repository that is not hosted on github.

In addition to the documentation I linked in the previous paragraph, there is also a [Github blog on the topic of submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/).